# Running Kubuntu on 2 -1 tablet (Dell Latitude 5175)

Tags: customization, touchscreen, scaling, display-rotation, onscreen-keyboard

After a long uphill battle to get linux running on my tablet I finally decided to write here.

I am trying to run a stable linux distro on my 2 in 1 tablet with touchscreen functionality and all the bells and whistles that windows 10 and android offer.

-My first problem is none of the desktop environments except KDE offer fractional scaling, which in my tablet all the environments look too small or too big.

-I settled for KDE but touchscreen is only recognized as a mouse left click, onscreen keyboard disappeared and screen won't auto rotate.

-I installed Ubuntu desktop from kubuntu and now I run both environments. All the tablet functionality works great in gnome but still face the issue of scaling, which I managed to mitigate a bit by using Font scaling in the settings.

-My issue now is that the apps I installed in KDE environment won't properly work on gnome or open, and customizing gnome seems too much of a hassle (i rather have the app drawer as a list instead of icons).

Is there a way to get the touchscreen/tablet functionality of gnome running on the KDE side? I don't really understand how the tablet can work perfectly on one environment and not the other one.

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't provided any release details (ie. what release are you talking about, newer releases will have better HiDpi & fractional scaling support).  Please provide release details

Comment: Currently running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2, Kernel 5.3.0-28, also have the latest KDE installed.